# Unsuccessful attempt to use .destroy() to wipe data results from GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying out my hand with Tkinter in building a GUI where users can track an item they enter the ID for. Pretty much all of it is done, but I'm running into an issue with using .destroy()

What I would like to happen is when a user selects a button, it destroys all displayed table results. Right now, the table results remain without error. Based on the code snippet below, does anything stand out?

```
global searched_label
searched_label.destroy()

search = tracking_id_entry.get()
sql = "SELECT * FROM table_desc WHERE tracking_id = %s"
name = (search,)
my_cursor.execute(sql, name)
result = my_cursor.fetchall()

if not result:
    result = "Tracking ID Not Found..."
    searched_label = Label(screen, text=result)
    searched_label.grid(row=7, columnspan=2, sticky=EW)

else:
    for index, x in enumerate(result):
        num = 0
        index += 7
        for y in x:
            searched_label = Label(screen, text=y)
            searched_label.grid(row=index, column=num)
            num += 1
```

Comment: First `for y in x` block should be inside `for index, x in enumerate(result)` block.  Since you used same variable for all the labels created in the for loop, so only the last label will be destroyed by `searched_label.destroy()`.  You need to use a list to store those labels and go through that list to destroy all the labels.

Comment: Yea the first part was a typo on my end here on stackoverflow. So the searched_label.destroy is deleting the "if" statement. I am having trouble with the else statement. That's where the previous label does not delete when i place another id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you used same variable `searched_label` for all the labels, so only the last label will be destroyed by the line `searched_label.destroy()`.

You can use a list to store the created labels and then you can go through this list to destroy all the labels:

```py
labels = []  # list to store the labels

# assume the posted code is inside a function
def show_tracking():
    # destroy existing labels
    for lbl in labels:
        lbl.destroy()
    labels.clear() # clear the list

    # populate new labels
    search = tracking_id_entry.get()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM table_desc WHERE tracking_id = %s"
    name = (search,)
    my_cursor.execute(sql, name)
    result = my_cursor.fetchall()

    if not result:
        result = "Tracking ID Not Found..."
        searched_label = Label(screen, text=result)
        searched_label.grid(row=7, columnspan=2, sticky=EW)
        labels.append(searched_label) # add the label to the list

    else:
        for index, x in enumerate(result):
            num = 0
            index += 7
            for y in x:
                searched_label = Label(screen, text=y)
                searched_label.grid(row=index, column=num)
                labels.append(searched_label) # add the label to the list
                num += 1
```